# Cannot play audio tag in WebView: Android Lollipop

Tags: android, html5-audio, audio-streaming

It's been hours, and still I cannot get anything on the topic. I searched a lot, still there is no help.

What I have done so far (of course this is not only what I have tried) which looks obvious, is as below:

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
```

**MainAcitivity:**

```
WebView webMain = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.my_web_view);

        webMain.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/testing.html");
        webMain.setWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient(getApplication()));
```

**activity_main:**

```
<WebView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/my_web_view"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/app_bar" />
```

I can see the following but no sound is played:

[image]

**Logcat:**

```
02-12 10:06:53.535    6392-6429/org.example.android.flickrbrowser E/MediaResourceGetter﹕ Unable to configure metadata extractor
02-12 10:08:59.400    6492-6529/org.example.android.flickrbrowser D/MediaResourceGetter﹕ ethernet/wifi connection detected
02-12 10:09:08.114    6492-6529/org.example.android.flickrbrowser D/MediaResourceGetter﹕ resource doesn't have video
```

Any help or some link is appreciated. Thank you so much

**EDIT**

testing.html

This file contains the `<audio>` tag of html

```
<audio style="margin-top:20px; padding-left: 10px;" title="Thing" src="http://someipaddress:port/;" controls="controls" autoplay=""></audio>
```

Comment: Could you post your `testing.html` as well?

Comment: It is working perfectly, I have checked on chrome

Comment: @DanailAlexiev see the edit

Comment: Do you explicitly need to play it in an embedded `WebView`? Have you considered using the `MediaPlayer`? You can set the URL using `setDataSource(String path)`.

Comment: So you mean, using __MediaPlayer__  and setting a URL, audio can be played?

Comment: @DanailAlexiev The problem is, I only have access to that html tag. It is kind of api for me

Comment: Yes, `MediaPlayer` supports this. To be completely honest, I haven't tried it, but the documents explicitly say it supports streaming from an url using this method. The only idea I can give you is to maybe try it just to see if it works. If it does, you can try and parse the audio tag, extract the needed information and use the native components to achieve your goal. If you are going to bundle the HTML page in the app, you can just use the provided URL and stream from it.

Answer (score 4):

That is enough to me

webMain.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webMain.getSettings().setMediaPlaybackRequiresUserGesture(false);

Answer (score -1):

Make your main activity next

**MainAcitivity:**

```
WebView webMain = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.my_web_view);
        webMain.setWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient());
        webMain.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webMain.getSettings().setMediaPlaybackRequiresUserGesture(false);
        webMain.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
        webMain.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/testing.html");
```

To Manifest add:

```
android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
```